# Find all pairs of $(n,k)$ where $n ≥ 2$ and $k$ is a prime number such that $log_n (n + k)$ is rational

Tags: prime-numbers, logarithms

I found the following math question interesting:

> Find all pairs of (n,k) where n ≥ 2 and k is a prime number such that log_n (n + k) is rational.

I tried this by contradicting certain statements such as:

```
log_n (n+k)=2  and  log_n (n+k)=C
```

I contradicted both (final contradiction shown below):

```
k=n(n-1)             -- Contradiction since k is a prime number (except n=2)

k=(n^(C-1))(n-1)     -- Contradiction again since k is a prime number
```

However, I don't know if I did them correct nor how to go from here. What would be the next steps? Are my contradictions correct? If possible can you please explain how you would attack this question with a possible solution?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does it mean for a number to be true? Or did I misread something?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Sorry my mistake, it was meant to be "... such that log_n (n + k) is rational." Edited now.

Comment: Hint: The only pair is (2, 2). Try letting the logarithm be equal to p/q, where p and q are coprime.

Comment: Yup I just did that. And is the only answer (2,2)? How do you definitely know? I also got that but wasn't sure if it was the only one.

Comment: I know that because I solved the problem. You can try following my hint.

Comment: n+k=n^(p/q)       to      k=n(n^(p/q-1)-1).         There is numbers in the solution of a+sqrt(x)=x where a is a prime number.       Would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=n^p=(n+k)^q$ where $p,q$ are coprime.

Since $A$ is both a $p$-th and $q$-th power, $A=a^{pq}$ where $a$ is an integer. Can you now express $k$ in terms of $a$?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify why does A = n^p = (n+k)^q?

Comment: @AnhadArora Which of the two equalities are you confused about?

Comment: How did you get $n^p = (n+k)^q$?

Comment: @AnhadArora If $\log_n (n + k)=\frac pq$ then $n^{\frac pq}=n+k$

Comment: @AnhadArora Let $\log_{n}(n+k)$ be $p/q$. By definition $n^{p/q}=n+k$. Now take the $q$-th power.